If $\sqrt a\leq\sqrt b+\sqrt c$, then $\sqrt{a+x}\leq\sqrt{b+\left(\frac1k\right)^2x}+\sqrt{c+\left(\frac{k-1}{k}\right)^2x}$, for $k\geq1$
I am trying to prove the following: given $a,b,c \geq 0$ such that:
$$
\sqrt{a} \leq \sqrt{b} + \sqrt{c}
$$
and $k\geq 2$, show that:
$$
\sqrt{a+x} \leq \sqrt{b+\left( \frac{1}{k}\right)^2x} + \sqrt{c +\left( \frac{k-1}{k}\right)^2x}
$$
I know this looks a bit strange, so for example, if $k=2$ we would need to show that:
$$
\sqrt{a+x} \leq \sqrt{b+\frac{x}{4}} + \sqrt{c +\frac{x}{4}}
$$
for all $x\geq 0$. For $k=3$ we need:
$$
\sqrt{a+x} \leq \sqrt{b+\frac{x}{9}} + \sqrt{c +\frac{4x}{9}}
$$
Here is my attempt. We square and expand:
$$
\left( \sqrt{b+\left( \frac{1}{k}\right)^2x} + \sqrt{c +\left( \frac{k-1}{k}\right)^2x} \right)^2 = b+c +\frac{(k-1)^2+1}{k^2}x + 2\sqrt{bc+\frac{(k-1)^2b+c}{k^2}x+ \frac{(k-1)^2}{k^4}x^2 }
$$
then if we can show that:
$$
2\sqrt{bc} + \frac{(2k-2)}{k^2}x  \leq 2\sqrt{bc+\frac{(k-1)^2b+c}{k^2}x+ \frac{(k-1)^2}{k^4}x^2 } \tag{1}
$$
we can plug this in to find:
$$
 a+x \leq b+c + 2\sqrt{bc} + x\leq \left( \sqrt{b+\left( \frac{1}{k}\right)^2x} + \sqrt{c +\left( \frac{k-1}{k}\right)^2x} \right)^2
$$
and the result follows. To show (1) we again square both sides of (1). The left side is:
$$
4bc + \frac{(2k-2)^2}{k^4}x^2 + 4\sqrt{bc}\frac{2k-2}{k^2}x
$$
And the right side is:
$$
4(bc + \frac{(k-1)^2b+c}{k^2}x + \frac{(k-1)^2}{k^4}x^2)
$$
Canceling terms this comes down to showing that:
$$
2\sqrt{bc} \leq (k-1)b + c
$$
which is true because $bc$ is maximized when $b=c$ in which case $2\sqrt{bc} =2b=2c$. This completes the proof.
My attempt so far is detailed above. Suggestions, other proofs, and any help is welcome.

For a solution-verification question to be on topic you must specify precisely which step in the proof you question, and why so. This site is not meant to be used as a proof checking machine. $\ \ $

Please ask only one question per post. So here either ask a proper SV-question, or drop the checking question and keep the question about other proofs (then please explain why/what you seek in other proofs).

I see a triangle in here somewhere...

I take it your $x$ is non-negative. If so, you may want to get familiar with Minkowski's inequality, which can get you a one-line proof.

@Vic_Dis I'm not sure I understand how Minkowski's inequality can be applied here, could you elaborate?

By Minkowski and the given condition we have $$\begin{aligned}\sqrt{b+\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)^2x}+\sqrt{c+\left(\frac{k-1}{k}\right)^2x}&\ge\sqrt{\left(\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}\right)^2+\left(\frac{1}{k}\sqrt{x}+\frac{k-1}{k}\sqrt{x}\right)^2}\\&\ge\sqrt{\left(\sqrt{a}\right)^2+\left(\sqrt{x}\right)^2}\end{aligned}$$
as desired.

Please do not answer off-topic questions - see the comments on the question.
